# MySQL table with a primary key, and two other keys. Trouble copying schema to existing table with data

Tags: mysql, database, key, primary-key

I am copying the schema of an empty table in a newer version of ISPConfig into the database of an older version. In the newer version, there are two keys and a primary key. Here's the second key, missing from the table with data. As you can see it says "MUL" indicating it is a non-unique key:

```
*************************** 10. row ***************************  
  Field: type  
   Type: enum('alias','aliasdomain','forward','catchall')  
   Null: NO  
    Key: MUL  
Default: alias  
  Extra:
```

On the other table, with data, MUL is missing:

```
*************************** 10. row ***************************  
  Field: type  
   Type: enum('alias','aliasdomain','forward','catchall')  
   Null: NO  
    Key:  
Default: alias  
  Extra:
```

Is there any way I can add "MUL" to the 'type' column without data loss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` to see all the indexes in each table. Then use `ALTER TABLE oldtable ADD INDEX ...` to add the missing indexes to the old table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html) with `DROP KEY` to remove an index, and then add another index with `ADD KEY`.

It may take some time to rebuild the (new) index, but it won't affect the data in the database.